# How can I format all the keys in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a cursor that I converted to dictionary. After conversion I would like to modify all the keys by adding to all them **"_A"**

What I currently have:

```
my_request = collection_db.find_one({"id": 1})
my_dict = dict()
if my_request is not None:
    for key, val in my_request.items():
        if key != '_id':
            my_dict[key + str('_A')] = val
```

is there a better way to do this? for example with `dict()` function?

```
my_request = collection_db.find_one({"id": 1})
my_dict = dict(my_request)
del my_dict['_id']
# formating all the keys?
```

Comment: Can you create a new dictionary instead? E.g. `{f"{key}_A": value for key, value in d.items() if key != "_id"}`. What does *"better"* mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd pop the id to avoid the if statement, create a new dict with the keys you want, then add the id in after

```
my_id = my_request.pop("_id")
my_dict = {f"{key}_A": val for key, val in my_request.items()}
my_dict["_id"] = my_id
```

Answer (score 2):

See below

```
d1 = {'A': ('a', 'b'), 'B': ('c', 'd'), 'C': ('e', 'f')}


def a_condition_on_key(key):
    # add your key logic here
    return True


d2 = {k + '_A': v for k, v in d1.items() if a_condition_on_key(k)}

print(d2)
```